# preg_replace to put forward slash in IMG tag

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have the following code, but it replaces every img tag with just: <img />  I need all of the attributes included in the replacement.

For example, this:

    `<img src="images/myimg.gif" alt="">`

Is supposed to turn into this:

    `<img src="images/myimg.gif" alt="" />`

Here is my current non-working code:

    `$html = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "<img $1 />", $html);`

Answer (score 3):

```
$html = preg_replace("@(<img.*?)(?<!/)>@i", "$1/>", $html);
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! this site should help others to learn and understand .. using negative lookbehind is a good idea, i posted the same answer. but you should include some explanation and/or links in your answers. nevertheless, +1 for thinking about negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `$1` you need at first to store something into it. this is done by a capturing group, meaning simply put brackets around the pattern you want to reuse.

```
$html = preg_replace("/<img([^>]+)\>/i", "<img $1 />", $html);
```

There are several online tools where you can test your regexes, see your regex e.g. [here on RegExr](http://regexr.com?2volh)

You can find more about groups [here on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 2):

This regex may work for you, but if applied repeatedly, it will insert the `/` again and again, resulting in `<img ... / / / / />` and so on:

```
$html = preg_replace("/<img([^>]+)\>/is", "<img \1 />", $html);
```

To avoid this, you can use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!\/)`:

```
$html = preg_replace("/<img([^>]+)(?<!\/)\>/is", "<img \1 />", $html);
```

it matches only image tags, that are *not* closed with a `/>`

Answer (score 1):

Add the brackets around the attributes in the regex, then you can use $1 in in the replacer:

```
$html = preg_replace("/<img([^>]+)\>/i", "<img $1 />", $html);
```

Also see this [example](http://ideone.com/DyjLZ).

Comment: To be valid an image tag must have an alt attribute. So at least one character is needed (and + instead of *).

Comment: also a `src` is mandatory. but one random character isn't enough. if you want this regex to only change *valid* image tags, a lookahead for both `src` and `alt` could serve that purpose. but i guess validation is overkill in this use case.